# How to remove SoapUI?

Tags: uninstall

I've installed SoapUI by downloading it from its website (http://www.soapui.org/), but I would now like to uninstall it.  However, it installed using its own little installer so I don't know what/where it added.  Is there an elegant way to remove it or to remove a software that installs like this in general?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
rinzwind@discworld:~/SmartBear/soapUI-4.6.0$ ls
bin          jre       LICENSE.txt  soapUI-4.6.0.desktop  UserGuide.url
hermesJMS    lib       README.md    soapUI.url            wsi-test-tools
JavaDoc.url  licences  readme.txt   uninstal
```

See the file named `uninstall`? ;)

```
rinzwind@discworld:~/SmartBear/soapUI-4.6.0$ ./uninstall 
testing JVM in /home/rinzwind/SmartBear/soapUI-4.6.0/jre ...
```

[image]

Comment: Umm... weird, the "installer" that I got (a sh script) doesn't have any of this...

Comment: I downloaded the Linux version from the link in the OP (http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui/4.6.0/soapUI-x32-4.6.0.sh/download)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an elegant way to remove it

There should be. It could be using the same installation file then using `--uninstall` or looking in the installation folder for some `uninstall.sh` script. Unless they decided not to provide a easy uninstallation method in which case you should hunt down and remove every bit.

> remove a software that installs like this in general?

As stated above, each developer has their own method. Is difficult to tell: all `.sh` scripts has to be uninstalled this or either way. Is one of the headache of sysadmins and power users that keep track of each piece of software. Normally is recommended to use software included in the repositories with their respective package manager since the methods of installation, upgrade and uninstallations are homogeneous and all of them follow it.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest, since their FAQ and forum have no uninstall directions, that you register at http://www.soapui.org/Downloads/download-soapui-pro-trial.html as a Trial User then post in their support forum http://forum.soapui.org/viewforum.php?f=2&sid=7389286a6f3eb18ce6c5d5bf8bb7f2bf to ask for their assistance.